# how to can convert hard coded values list of lists to use Add() method c#?

Tags: c#, list

I want to convert hard coded values list of lists to use Add() method but, i  can't do it.i am writing a little bit code for it but it doesn't work.
i put original code for understand better. actually,`*pictureBox1_MouseClick*` is original code.

```
 private List<List<Node>> graph = new List<List<Node>>();
        private List<Node> ListNode = new List<Node>();
        private Node node = new Node();
 private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);
            if (result != -1)
            {
                circlesSourceAndDestination.Add(circleManager.Circles[result]);
                if (Count == 1)
                {
                    node.Id = result;
                }
                else if (Count == 2)
                {
                    var weigth = CalculateLengthSourceAndDestination(circlesSourceAndDestination);
                    if (weigth < 0)
                    {
                        weigth *= -1;
                    }
                     ListNode.Add(node);

                    graph.Add(ListNode);


                    Count = 0;
                }
                Count++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);
            if (result != -1)
            {
                circleManager.Circles[circleManager.HitTest(e.Location)].Selected = true;
                circleManager.Circles[result].SelectFillColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

---

```
List<Node> graph = new List<Node>() {
            new Node() {
                Id = 0, Neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 1,127),
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 2,100),
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 4,139),
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 6,117),
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 7,156)
                }
            },
            new Node() {
                Id = 1, Neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 0,127),
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 2,102),
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 3,108),
                   new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 7,53)
                }
            }

    public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        Neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Neighbors { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? could you post the code where you "use Add() method " ?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a new `Node` and `.Add()` to your graph like this:

```
Node newNode = new Node();
//Assign Node Id
newNode.Id = 2; 
//Declare a new List for Neighbors in Node
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> neighborList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
//Add members to neighborList
neighborList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1)); //Assign these values dynamically;
neighborList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 2)); 
neighborList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3, 3));
//Assign neighborList to Neighbors
//Note that this could have been done without declaring a separate List
newNode.Neighbors = neighborList;
//Add newNode to your List
graph.Add(newNode);
```

Comment: i don't want use hard coded values it should be dynamic added values.

Comment: I believe I provided the information that you need, even with extra details. You should work on it and find the solution yourself, so that you actually learn it. If you are stuck somewhere, feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Dictionary<int, int>` instead of `List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>`. Then you can do the following:

```
public class Node {
    ...
    public Dictionary<int, int> Neighbors { get; set; }
}


Neighbors.Add(0,127);
Neighbors.Add(3,108);
...
```